# Joomla MySQL date loses a day

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I got a problem I can't get the hang of.

We created a backend extension for Joomla running with a MySQL database.
In the backend form there is a date field.
On all our development enviroments that date field works correctly.

On our customers enviroment the date field always loses a day.
We checked php versions, MySQL version and time zones.
Even the Joomla installations are veritable clones.

All seems in order. A debug revealed php and sql timezone offsets to be +2 in all instances and enviroments.

In order to debug we created two dummy entries, one by taking the php time and sending it as string to the database for parsing.
The second dummy made use of the sql intern NOW(), respectively CURDATE() function.
Both dummies showed correct values.

But when I send a string representing a time through the Joomla Admin field, form and table structure it always looses a day. But only on our customers site, not in our development sites.

I need ideas where else to look to debug this. Thank you.